# Does mold in a loggia means that the loggia must be replaced?

Tags: windows, mold, condensation, window-frame

My apartment has a loggia which used to be a balcony (it is now an extension of the living room without any separation between them - the door that was there was removed). This was done by the previous owner.

In the architectural drawing below :) the parts in blue are aluminium frames and double windows that were attached to the lower and upper edge of the balcony (so mine, and the one above) and the security rail (the black vertical bars). You can see such a balcony on the last picture in this post on the facing building.

[image]

The apartment is well heated and aerated but I see mold on the loggia - specifically near the edges. As you can see on the pictures below, there is heavy condensation and the water is going down, but also on the ceiling, next to the aluminium frames of the loggia.

[image]

[image]

One other thing is that the apartment is heated from the floor, but obviously not the ex-balcony - this is a slab of concrete sticking out and cooling the living room (which is another problem). Both the upper and lower floors have similar loggias.

I would like to fix that and have it fixed by specialized companies. I would like however to get your advice in advance so not to be completely dumb when discussing with them. Specifically:

- are such cases common where there is significant condensation of water on frames?
- is this something that can be fixed with such aluminium loggia?
- or should I consider changing it → in which case what to pay attention to so that I do not end up with the same issue?

Comment: There is not going to be any simple solution due to the amount of moisture condensing on those aluminum window frames.  With that much water mold and water damage are inevitable.

Comment: @jwh20: yes, I realize that something must be done. My basic concern is whether such aluminium frames that get so much condensation can be kept by doing [something to the wall or whatever] or that such construction is simply not adapted to a loggia in my weather. The whole apartment is perfectly fine, this is just that loggia that has a problem

Comment: The solution is to introduce a thermal break to keep the aluminum, which is an excellent conductor of heat, from conducting that heat out of your space.   I believe there are some products that coat the material or even add heat to reduce this but I am not sure how effective these are.  What you have a is a MAJOR source of heat loss and you may want to consult with some local companies that deal with remediating this issue.  Any of your neighbors have a similar problem (likely) and resolved it?

Comment: "The apartment is well heated and aerated" - how, if you only have radiant floor heat? Previous owner enlarged the envelope but then did nothing. Presumably your neighbors added forced air heat, still have a wall there, or have the same problem. Either add heat, remove water, or both (space heater and dehumidifier) or drop +$10k on some HVAC. - You're letting conditioned air meet unconditioned space; that's what happens.

Comment: ***[loggia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loggia)*** - a balcony with the two sides enclosed. Here it has had a fourth wall installed, incorporating it into the house.

Comment: @Mazura: *Loggia* → I took the Frech expression, it is actually a balcony (triangle of concrete sticking out of the building) that was enclosed by an aluminium/glass construction.

Comment: @Mazura: heating is conceivable but I think I will go for a new construction, making sure there is no heat bridge this time. AC is out of question. As for the heating, only the living room gets cool because of that extension (the balcony). All the other rooms are fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of condensation I see you may need to take multiple paths forward to reduce the condensation that is creating the mold growth.

The first and least expensive thing I’d to add a dehumidifier to reduce the moisture
.
The second thing would be to upgrade the framing and insulation.
One of the window pics looks like double Pane the others look single upgrading to fully insulated windows and frames can reduce the amount of condensation further than dehumidification alone.

To eliminate the mold I would use a 3% solution of hydrogen peroxide and water sprayed onto the ceiling and wood surfaces to kill the mold.
The great thing about hydrogen peroxide is it doesn’t stink and when done it leaves no chemical residue it breaks down into water and oxygen.